# Flutter Beacon Scanner not scan the beacon when application go in background

Tags: android, flutter, beacon, altbeacon

Hello I am using flutter `beacon 0.5.1` for scanning beacon in android device. After some time when application go in background beacon doesn't scan. It generates empty results. I've tried to implement native android code for that, but I faced the same result. what solution would be suitable here?

Answer (score 0):

If the result is empty, I think it is because of that you haven’t grant the permissions  of background location.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already added all the permission related to background location, foreground services , Access Fine location. But still same issue is happen.

Comment: Did you set the location permission to “always allow” for your app?

Comment: Yes I select "always allow" from option.